# Saving multiple input data in one .txt file. Is it possible to overwrite and get data from specific line?

Tags: java

Code first:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public String date;
    public String fridge1;
    public String fridge2;
    public String info;
    static final int lineNumber = 0;

    public Test(String date, String fridge1, String fridge2, String info) {
        this.date = date;
        this.fridge1 = fridge1;
        this.fridge2 = fridge2;
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getFridge1() {
        return fridge1;
    }

    public void setFridge1(String fridge1) {
        this.fridge1 = fridge1;
    }

    public String getFridge2() {
        return fridge2;
    }

    public void setFridge2(String fridge2) {
        this.fridge2 = fridge2;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
        date + "\n" +
            fridge1 + "\n" +
            fridge2 + "\n" +
            info + "\n";
    }

    public void saveData() {
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        boolean checker = true;

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.contains(date)) {
                    checker = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (checker) {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("text.txt", true)) {
                fos.write(toString().getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// Test test = new Test("19/02/1992", "10", "9", "ok");
// test.saveData();
 Test test2 = new Test("19/02/1900", "8", "4", "not ok");
        test2.saveData();

    }
}
```

I want to do program in Java to get some inputs and date, mostly Strings. I just create a methods to write all data in one .txt file, one data - 1 line. If there is already existing date program is not writing new data. Finally, I would like to overwrite data. If I put the same date in, I would like to overwrite existing date to new one. So in my mind if I have in .txt file this data:

line1 17/05/16 line2 blabla line3 blabla line4 blabla

and I will put in Main this:

```
Test test2 = new Test("17/05/16", "8", "4", "not ok");
       test2.saveData();
```

it should find where is 17/05/16 and then replace lines 2-4 like this.

line1 17/05/16
line2 8
line3 4
line4 not ok

It is possible? Then how to find out all data in reverse way? In mean when I would like to check my data from specific date ex. 17/05/16?

As you can see I just stuck in moment when I have to search where is my data. I can't find good methods.

Comment: I think for this task it would be a good option to use Spring Boot for this. A connected database in the background offers many easy options for managing text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added Main method.

Comment: *Mostly* strings. In your program parse the dates into `LocalDate` objects. You can always format them into `dd/MM/yyyy` format when presenting them to the user. And in your persistent storage — your text file — use ISO 8601 format, that is `yyyy-MM-dd`, so that it’s independent of what users want to see.

Answer (score 1):

When your program does start, your first step must always be reading whole text file into memory, line by line. Visit [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-text-file-into-java-hashmap/?ref=rp) how you can achive it. Use your timestamp as key for the HashMap.

One advantage of HashMap is, you can easily check of occurences or add some data at the end. And if you want just update an existing entry, use the same key and the content will be overwritten.

After this, [the next page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-hashmap-to-a-text-file-in-java/) demonstrate how to write the content back to your text file.

Please note: As I wrote in comment section the use of Spring Boot is a better option for your task.